# server certificate expired handshake failed?

Tags: tls

is it possible that the TLS handshake will fail if the server presents a certificate that is expired ? I can see CLient Hello, and next Server Hello + Certificate from Server and next the receiver  is sending a FIN packet to close abrupt the connection. May it be because the certificate expired few months back ?

thanks

Comment: Which part is the "receiver". The client or the server?

Comment: it is the client Steffen.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely.  An expired certificate is not a valid one.  A certificate should only be accepted if :

- it is signed by a valid authority - ie, there is a valid certificate chain back to a trusted root certificate authority
- it is for the subject that is being connected to - ie, hostname of the machine being connected to matches the subject name in the certificate (or subject alternative name)
- it is within date
- it has not been revoked (either by being included on the client's revocation list or through an online certificate status check from the certificate authority)

Get a valid cert.

Answer (score 4):

If the validation of the certificate fails the client sends either a TLS alert (well behaved) or just closes the connection (bad behaved but common). Since the validation failed because the certificate is expired this is probably what you see.